# JS/ES offline and store a Promise for later use

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-next

How can I offline this 'example' promise---
i.e. attributing the promise to a variable for later passing/use---

```
// this example promise works OK... 
// just test with x=0 and x<>0
var x=0; 
( new Promise( ( a, b ) => 
    { if ( x==1 ) a(); else b(); } ) )
    .then( ()=>console.log( "RS=>OK" ), ()=>console.log( "RJ=>KO" ) 
    )
```

I want to attribute the promise to a variable just like

```
var p = new Promise( ... )
```

but the promise is executed at creation time...

?how can I defer this execution for later
calling a method on the promise... for example : `p.exec()`

Comment: What's the actual use case? When is _"later"_? And what should `x.exec()` do when `x` is a number?

Comment: Functions are exactly what you need. They can be executed *later*.

Comment: Sorry @Andreas... write error...  it is p.exec()...

Comment: What you want is like asking someone to promise you something without telling the person what to promise. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Promises execute immediately.  But you could wrap them in a function that, when called, creates/executes the Promise.  For example:

```js
var p = () =>
  new Promise( ( a, b ) => 
    { if ( x==1 ) a(); else b(); } ) )
  .then( ()=>console.log( "RS=>OK" ), ()=>console.log( "RJ=>KO" );

// when ready to start
var actualPromise = p();
await actualPromise;
```

Comment: yes,,, that is the example I usully see,,,, but you are creating/storing it in an anonymous frunction to execute later... and I think it would be more benefic to receive a Promise.object... so we can 1. Reprogram it before execution,,, 2. Inspect it after execution,,, and 3. Reset/Reuse it,,,

Comment: @ZEE that's not how the Promise mechanism works.

Comment: @ZEE promises do not *start* later. Creating a promise constructs an already pending promise. There is no concept of "starting a promise later". What you might do is construct an *executor function* and pre-process it (via composition or whatever) before giving it to a promise constructor. However, I cannot think of a real use-case for that, instead I'd expect an async function to constructed/processed and then executed. Async functions implicitly return promises, so calling `async function foo() {}` would be basically the same as using the promise constructor but with more options to handle.