# JS/ES how can I reset/reuse a Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

How can reset the following 'example' promise---
so it can be 'consumed' again later...

```js
// example promise works OK... test with x=0/x<>0
var x = 0;
(new Promise((a, b) => { if (x == 1) a(); else b(); }))
  .then(() => console.log("RS=>OK"), () => console.log("RJ=>KO")
  )
```

How to reset the promise to reuse it again? Is there some functionality like `Promise.reset(p)`, or `p.reset()` we can use...?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I mean, what are you trying to achieve that makes you feel that that feature would be useful?

Comment: No, there isn't - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Are you looking for a function that you can just call again and again?

Comment: @Pointy Some "strange" stuff it seems: [JS/ES offline and store a Promise for later use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410339/)

Comment: Promises are markers for *already* ongoing operations. They represent a value that will be there in the future. But the implication is that something is trying to produce that value *now*, e.g., a network call. What you seem to describe is an operation that can be run later. That's called Task or Future and there are various implementations of those in different libraries. The intent there is to represent an operation that *will* run in the future and you can usually start/stop/cancel programmatically or wait for it to finish.

Comment: Combining your two questions on this topic, do you want to create a promise then later, (at a previously unknown time) resolve/reject it a once? If that's what you're trying to achieve, that's indeed possible. However, as your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/428538), it's hard to guess.

Comment: nop... that are 2 separate issues... that eventually... in a few cases... can meet...

Comment: @ZEE it's one core problem - wanting to treat Promises as if they represent an action you can star/stop/replay. So, in other words, *not* a Promise. If you explain what you're actually trying to do we can point you towards something that can help you with that. At the moment, we can just say that a Promise is the wrong tool but we don't know what the job is.